# How to select InnoDB or XtraDB as storage engine in MariaDB in Spring Boot 2 JPA application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am developing a new application using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 and Spring Data JPA. I am using MariaDB v10.
Below is my dev properties file.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect=MariaDB53Dialect
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=MariaDB53Dialect
```

I get output:

```
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
```

I am not able to change the storage engine. All the tables are being created using storage engine MyISAM.

I am able to create tables manually using other storage engines. But for some reason Spring or Hibernate falls back to MyISAM engine only.

With pure Hibernate-Java application, Hibernate uses InnoDB as default.

> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
>
> Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB

Is there any way to override Database storage engine from the Spring Boot properties?

Comment: Are you sure that you’re using the same configuration in each case? Perhaps the dialect or storage engine (`hibernate.dialect.storage_engine`) has been configured differently. Can you provide [minimal examples](/help/mcve) of both?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I used `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=InnoDB` but same results. I will post code in few hours.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson  I posted a very simple application here [Inline Link](https://github.com/icewheel/springjpshibernatedemo.git). Please run it and see the logs. Meantime I am debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [described in Spring Boot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties), all properties prefixed with `spring.jpa.properties` are passed through to the underlying JPA provider (Hibernate in this case) with the prefix removed.

The Hibernate property to configure the dialect is `hibernate.dialect` and its value should be the fully qualified class name of the dialect that you want to use. In this case that's `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect`.

Putting the above together, you could set the following property in your `application.properties`:

```
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
```

With this in place your Spring Boot-based application uses the MariaDB dialect:

```
2017-11-09 14:18:17.557  INFO 69955 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
```

Comment: this works for the current stable version of Spring. Wow it picked up right settings for Spring Boot 2...but there is some other issue...let me see in code.

Comment: For Spring Boot v2.0.0.M6 I am getting error:
`Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [MariaDB53Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]`. I use the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=MariaDB53Dialect`, its able to identify the change but throwing error.

Comment: The value of the property is wrong. It needs to be `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect` not just `MariaDB53Dialect`.

Comment: Wow...its working....so it needs the fully Qualified name of the class representing the dialect. Thanks @Andy

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 5.2.12, if I run the `MySQLStoredProcedureTest` while setting the dialect to MariaDB:

```
@RequiresDialect(MariaDB53Dialect.class)
public class MySQLStoredProcedureTest 
        extends BaseEntityManagerFunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getAnnotatedClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {
            Person.class,
            Phone.class,
        };
    }
    
    ...
    
}
```

The `Post` entity is mapped as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String nickName;

    private String address;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    @Version
    private int version;

    //Getters and setter omitted for brevity
}
```

And, when I run the test on MariaDB, Hibernate generates the following schema:

```
create table Person (
   id bigint not null,
    address varchar(255),
    createdOn datetime(6),
    name varchar(255),
    nickName varchar(255),
    version integer not null,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB
```

That's because `MariaDB53Dialect` extends the `MariaDBDialect` which uses the `InnoDBStorageEngine`:

```
public class MariaDBDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
    public MariaDBDialect() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean supportsRowValueConstructorSyntaxInInList() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected MySQLStorageEngine getDefaultMySQLStorageEngine() {
        return InnoDBStorageEngine.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

So, it's impossible to get MyISAM with `MariaDB53Dialect` when generating the schema with hbm2ddl.

However, you should only be using hbm2ddl to generate the initial script. In a production environment, you should use a tool [like FlywayDB](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/).

We actually wrote this in the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation):

> Although the automatic schema generation is very useful for testing
> and prototyping purposes, in a production environment, it’s much more
> flexible to manage the schema using incremental migration scripts.

We [changed this in Hibernate 5.2.8](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/16/mariadb-dialects/), so I suppose you are using an older version instead, otherwise, there is no explanation why you'd see MyISAM in your hbm2ddl auto-generated schema.

Check the dependencies using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and make sure you are really using Hibernate 5.2.12.

Comment: That's the issue the dialect the application uses is not MariaDB53Dialect. It uses MySql by default, somewhere in Spring it is happening. I tried to override it using properties but it does not happen.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot, it selects the best Hibernate version itself automatically.

Comment: Spring Boot v2.0.0.M6 uses Hibernate 5.2.12.Final.

Comment: You need to debug it through and see why the Dialect you provided was not picked. Once you fix that, it will work as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I posted a very simple application here [Inline Link](https://github.com/icewheel/springjpshibernatedemo.git). Meantime I am debugging.

Comment: Here is the working Hibernate-Java application that correctly pickup the dialect. [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/icewheel/HelloHibernate.git)

Comment: thanks @Vlad its working now. It was the Spring prefix that I had to apply to hibernate properties like `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect` and its working.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful